# How does the total attack bonus work

Tags: dnd-3.5e

I have a level one character whose *to hit* and *damage* figures seem overpowered to me.
**Is this how it is meant to be, or did I do something wrong?**

I rolled 4d6 and got a Dexterity of 16, which means a Dex modifier of +8.

My Base Attack Bonus is +1, so my ranged attack bonus will be +9, then my total attack bonus is 10.

The weapon damage is 1d8, then if the Dex mod is really an 8 that's a 17 total.

Comment: How do you expect to get 26 Dex at level 1, anyway?

Comment: Please tell us more about this character.  As Tuggy points out, a +8 Dex modifier implies a 26 Dexterity, which seems abnormally high for a level 1 character.  For example, if you're using some oddball race from a sourcebook that has a +8 racial bonus (on top of an 18 rolled on dice), there's a good chance you're forgetting to account for an ECL penalty or something.

Comment: Never mind I did it wrong

Comment: Unfortunately, your English is not the best and as it stands, it is very hard to undersand a large part of your question. I tried to improve it, but I still can't understand some points. How do you get that +10? It seems to be base attack bonus + dex modifier + some other +1 I can't identify. Same for damage, how can a +8 modifier, added to 1d8, be something greater than 16?

Answer (score 4):

You are right, those figures are off the charts for level one characters, you surely did something wrong. Let's check it step by step.

### The ability score roll

When you roll ability scores, the standard method is to roll 4d6, discard the lowest result, then add up the other three results.

This gives results between 3 and 18.

I don't see any evidence of you discarding the lowest roll, but let's suppose for a moment that you really rolled a 16 as the sum of your three highest dice.

### Calculating the modifier

An average character (10 or 11 Dex) has a modifier of +0
Your character, with a score of 16, has a modifier of +3

Check the score and modifier columns [in this table](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/theBasics.htm#tableAbilityModifiersandBonusSpells).
The math behind this is: mod=(score-10)/2 (round down).

### Your total attack bonus is off

Even if you really had a +8 Dex mod, adding it to a +1 Base Attack Bonus would only give you a ranged attack bonus of +9. I have no idea why your "total attack bonus" should be +10.

Your real ranged attack bonus is +4 = +1 BAB +3 Dex

### Your total damage is off

I do not really know what is going on here, but you have a +8 bonus on top of a d8, and somehow you total 17 damage. I might help you more once you edit some more details in your question, for now all I can say is that the value is surely not what it should be.